# LaTeX, fancyhdr

Tags: latex

I'm using fancyhdr package and I wonder if I can change size of the page number. I need 14 pt size but the auto size is about 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `fancyhdr` package provides a `\fancyfoot{}` macro. This can be used to change the formatting of the page numbering. So:

```
\fancyfoot[EO]{\large \thepage}
```

should do the trick. The page number will be displayed in a 14.4pt size. You might want to play with the selectors, i.e., the `[EO]`.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the way that the documentation shows?

```
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RO, LE] {\Huge \thepage}
```

works fine for me.